# A discrete local martingale which is integrable for some random $T>0$ is a true martingale up to time $T$.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, finance, local-martingales

Let $X$ be a discrete local martingale such that $X_T$ is integrable for some non-random
time $T > 0$. I am tasked with showing that $(X_t)_{0≤t≤T}$ is a true martingale.

The hint is to show that $X_{T-1}$ is integrable, and I think that the result would follow by induction. However, I really can't think where to start with achieving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your martingale is discrete-time, am I right? I was a bit confused by the word discrete hanging alone, because random variables can also be discrete. If so, I wonder if [Theorem C.5 of this document](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2018/fs/401-3888-00L/appendix/A3_Martingale-results.pdf) may be of assistance to you.